# Are there any ingredients I should not add to a no-knead dough with an extended proofing time?

Tags: baking, food-safety, dough, ingredient-selection

I am having great results with no-knead bread, generally leaving this to proof for up to 18 hours in a coolish (20 C) room.

I'm thinking of upping my game and adding fresh ingredients (e.g. minced fresh garlic, salami, tomato etc.) to the dough. Is there any ingredients I should avoid for food safety or quality reasons due to this long proofing time?

I will be using white bread flour and approximately 1/4 Tsp of bread machine yeast, and possibly sugar and olive oil as well.

Comment: I'm not sure on this so I'm not putting an answer, but most additives will to some extent affect the rise, how much affect depends on how much you are adding and what is added. Fresh ingredients might well spoil over that proof time, and things like salami add lots of salt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's anything specific to worry about with bread dough.  The important point is the temperature: if you're considering adding an ingredient that you normally wouldn't let sit out at room temperature for 18 hours for food safety reasons (and/or because it might start tasting "off"), you probably should add that ingredient toward the end by folding it in before shaping or something.

Most no-knead bread recipes that sit out at room temperature for a long time are quite flexible.  You likely won't cause any problems by folding in an ingredient late in the first rise.

Comment: Alternatively you could extend your proof even longer and do it in the fridge.

Answer (score 1):

I’m no expert but I’ve seen this discussed on The Great British Baking Show. They recommend adding things after the dough rises, when shaping the loaf. You could use the envelope fold method. I know it’s not strictly no-knead, but maybe close enough. One baking site thinks folding the dough a couple times improves the bread, regardless of additions. HTH!